# RSpec disable bypass_rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a decent-sized rails app with a bunch of controller specs.  All my controllers inherit from an `ApiController` which has a default error handler:

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :default_error_handler
```

The behavior I'm trying to get is:

1. By default, in specs, if an exception is thrown, that rescue_from is bypassed.  That way, when there's an exception in a spec, I can see the full stack trace in the rspec output.
2. For certain specific specs that are explicitly testing exception-throwing conditions, the rescue_from is *not* bypassed.

I can get #1 by using rspec's handy `bypass_rescue` function globally:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each do
    bypass_rescue
  end
end
```

However, I then need some way to specify the few cases where the rescue should not be bypassed.  Ideally, something like:

```
describe Api::V1::SomeController do
  it 'handles an exception' do
    dont_bypass_rescue
    get :something_that_throws_an_exception
  end
end
```

I can't seem to find a good way to accomplish this, though.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
config.before(:each, type: :controller) do |example|
  bypass_rescue unless example.metadata[:with_rescue]
end
```

Then:

```
describe Api::V1::SomeController do
  it 'handles an exception', with_rescue: true do
    get :something_that_throws_an_exception
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, that was much more straightforward than I expected.  Didn't know you could access the example and its metadata from a before block.  Thanks!